# How do I put a Bootstrap Glyphicon inside an asp:Button in ASP.Net?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, button, aspbutton

I'm using Bootstrap 3 in my project, and I want to use Bootstrap Glyphicons in ASP.net buttons.

Here is the code I used, though it didn't work out (I got a sample which uses Twitter Bootstrap `<span>` tags instead of `<i>` tags):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRandom"
    runat="server"
    Text="<span aria-hidden='true'
        class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'>
        </span>"
    onclick="btnRandom_Click" />
```

Maybe something extra should be done.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: you could subclass it and override the render method.

Comment: I could not understand what you mean Daniel, can you post a link or a sample code?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You have to use **asp:LinkButton** *instead of* a **asp:Button**, here is how it works for me using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) in an ASP.NET web-application:

From your code you can make the following work:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnRandom" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn btn-primary"    
            OnClick="btnRandom_Click">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Here is an example of what I use for a **Submit Button** with text "Submit":

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitBtn" 
                runat="server" 
                CssClass="btn btn-primary"    
                OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Submit
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Why the **<i>** tag instead of the usual **<span>** tag?

Comment: @skia.heliou: Using a <span> tag works too, and I believe <span> is better than <i> in this context. The <i> tag is suggesting a visual change however, it is not applied since there is no text. The <i> tag will soon be deprecated. I have updated my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

What is real use of `ASP Server` control when you can do that in `HTML` server control :

You can convert the HTML element to a server control by setting the runat="server" attribute.

```
<button runat="server" >
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Refresh
</button>
```

Comment: Can you get Server-Side OnClick to fire?

Comment: By using **onserverclick** event : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Souregi: Thanks for that, very cool! Learn something new everyday.

Comment: You're welcome :) if this solution suits you, hit the **green** button

Comment: Well I also posted an answer using LinkButton. But I also like your approach, its up to the developer to choose between HTML-Button or ASP:Link/Button

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
<button id="btnSubSearch" runat="server" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onserverclick="btnSubSearch_Click">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linkButton instead of button or asp:Button just like this;

```
<linkbutton runat="server"><a class="btn btn-info btn-md"> <span 
 class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="font-size: x-large; font-weight: 
 bolder"></span> </a></linkbutton>
```

Answer (score 1):

its work **for Asp:Button** glyphicon style:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-search">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" BackColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </div>
```