# put a Bootstrap Glyphicon inside an asp Button in ASP.Net

Tags: c#

This is my ASP button:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnexexcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" CssClass="btn icon-btn btn-info"
                OnClick="btnexexcel_Click" ></asp:Button>
```

This is my Glyphicon:

```
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-share img-circle text-info"></span>
```

Can you guide me how to use it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to use a Glyph instead of a button, have a button with the glyph on it instead of some text, or something else?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285570/how-do-i-put-a-bootstrap-glyphicon-inside-an-aspbutton-in-asp-net/24288560

Answer (score 0):

I use the "span" tag after the text

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Registrar **<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>**</asp:LinkButton>
```