# Adding glyphicon to asp.net button using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap/asp.net so I must be doing something wrong.
All I want is a glyphicon from bootstrap to show up next to my button. As I understand, I cannot use asp:Button, but must use LinkButton.

Code:

```html
//Head 

<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


//Body

<form id="defaultform" runat="server">
  <div class="container">
   <asp:LinkButton    ID="ButtonGetProduct" 
                      runat="server" 
                      CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"    
                      OnClick="ButtonGetProductName_Click">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>Register
    </asp:LinkButton>

  </div>
</form>
```

EDIT: Just added     to my header, then replaced "glyphicon glyphicon-barcode" with "fa fa-barcode".. works just fine now!

Comment: There's not glyphicons in Bootstrap 4 (_if you haven't added them manually_)

Comment: Anywhere I can read on how to add them manually?
EDIT: Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a Bootstrap Glyphicon inside an asp:Button in ASP.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285570/how-do-i-put-a-bootstrap-glyphicon-inside-an-aspbutton-in-asp-net)

Comment: @VDWWD that's exactly what I followed, didn't work. Probably because glyphicons were dropped in bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

I am using bootstrap 3.

Comment: Doesn't work with bootstrap 4. Unless you add them manually as VDWWD explained in the post above. Using <i> or <span> doesn't matter.